# How to store API keys in a PyPI project?

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, pypi

How do I store API keys in my code, which I will be uploading on PyPI? I do not want people to be able to download the raw package file and view the API keys.

Comment: So why would you want to store them there at all?

Comment: Please check my answer. If you need more explanation just drop a comment, I am happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

The architecture of your application is wrong in my view.

From my understanding 2 cases are possible.

1. The API key you are putting in your application works on a 3rd party API.

   In which case you should ask the user to generate their own API keys and initialise your app with those API keys to use your module.

This is how twitter/ Google/ Github, all most all other python module works.

Example : https://github.com/inueni/birdy

```
from birdy.twitter import UserClient
client = UserClient(CONSUMER_KEY,
                    CONSUMER_SECRET,
                    ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
```

2. You are providing your own service and you are accessing it using API keys.

In which case you should provide users an end point to generate an API key and use that again to initialise the module.

**Why should you do so?**

The whole point of having API keys and not public-ally available open endpoint is security. You should be able to individually throttle API keys which are bombarding you with requests.

If you have 1 API keys for all module download then, every user of the module will be using the same api keys. You will not be able to throttle anyone.

Also No security (anyone who downloads the module will be able to see the keys).

To change API keys you will have to update your module and re-deploy. And all users of your module will have to pip upgrade to use your module.